# Could not find method getAaptOptions() for arguments [] on task

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to use the Tinker.When I use the Gradle order "buildTinkerPatchRelease",but after it started,something goes wrong.And  it stop.

> Could not find method getAaptOptions() for arguments [] on task ':app:processReleaseResources' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.

Because of this , I cannot make a patch apk to continue Tinker.

"I've tried change the buildToolsVersion and update my buildTool ,the latest version is 29.0.2,but it still didn't work.
"

```
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :app:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceRelease
> Task :app:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :app:generateReleaseResources
> Task :app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests

> Task :app:processReleaseManifest
C:\Users\ODM\Documents\GitHub\android-databinding\TinkerDemo\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-27:56 Warning:
    activity#com.tencent.bugly.beta.ui.BetaActivity@tools:name was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:23 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
C:\Users\ODM\Documents\GitHub\android-databinding\TinkerDemo\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-27:56 Warning:
    activity#com.tencent.bugly.beta.ui.BetaActivity@tools:configChanges was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:23 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
C:\Users\ODM\Documents\GitHub\android-databinding\TinkerDemo\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-27:56 Warning:
    activity#com.tencent.bugly.beta.ui.BetaActivity@tools:theme was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:23 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
C:\Users\ODM\Documents\GitHub\android-databinding\TinkerDemo\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:29:9-39:20 Warning:
    provider#com.tencent.bugly.beta.utils.BuglyFileProvider@tools:name was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:29 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
C:\Users\ODM\Documents\GitHub\android-databinding\TinkerDemo\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:29:9-39:20 Warning:
    provider#com.tencent.bugly.beta.utils.BuglyFileProvider@tools:authorities was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:29 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
C:\Users\ODM\Documents\GitHub\android-databinding\TinkerDemo\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:29:9-39:20 Warning:
    provider#com.tencent.bugly.beta.utils.BuglyFileProvider@tools:exported was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:29 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
C:\Users\ODM\Documents\GitHub\android-databinding\TinkerDemo\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:29:9-39:20 Warning:
    provider#com.tencent.bugly.beta.utils.BuglyFileProvider@tools:grantUriPermissions was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:29 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
C:\Users\ODM\Documents\GitHub\android-databinding\TinkerDemo\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    meta-data#android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS@tools:name was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:0 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
C:\Users\ODM\Documents\GitHub\android-databinding\TinkerDemo\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    meta-data#android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS@tools:resource was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:0 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present

> Task :app:tinkerProcessReleaseManifest
tinker add tinker_id_patch-1.0.0 to your AndroidManifest.xml C:\Users\ODM\Documents\GitHub\android-databinding\TinkerDemo\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml
tinker add com.example.odm.tinkerdemo.application.MyApplication to dex loader pattern
tinker gen AndroidManifest.xml in build/intermediates/tinker_intermediates/AndroidManifest.xml

> Task :app:tinkerProcessReleaseResourceId
we build app apk with apply resource mapping file C:\Users\ODM\Documents\GitHub\android-databinding\TinkerDemo\app\build\bakApk/app-0915-20-24-52/app-release-R.txt

> Task :app:tinkerSupportProcessReleaseManifest
manifestPath: C:\Users\ODM\Documents\GitHub\android-databinding\TinkerDemo\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml
app version:1.0.0.1
Remove TINKER_ID tinker_id_patch-1.0.0
tinkerSupport add com.example.odm.tinkerdemo.application.MyApplication to dex loader pattern
tinkerSupport gen AndroidManifest.xml in build/intermediates/bugly_intermediates/AndroidManifest.xml

> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Could not find method getAaptOptions() for arguments [] on task ':app:processReleaseResources' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I expect I can fix the stange problem! May someone can give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,
 dependencies {

```
    classpath 'com.tencent.bugly:tinker-support:1.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

app buildgradle:

```
implementation 'com.tencent.tinker:tinker-android-lib:1.9.14'
```

root buildgradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'

classpath "com.tencent.bugly:tinker-support:1.2.0"
```

Hope it helps?